# awesome-typescript-loader does not pick up changes in JSON

Tags: json, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, awesome-typescript-loader

Assume I have some JSON file (let's name it `template.json`)

```
{
    "myField1": "",
    "myField2": ""
}
```

I also have a kind of generic class

```js
export default GenericClass<T> {
    // Creating an empty constuctor with passed type.
    // to allow define type automatically.
    // This allow us not to manually set generic type for class
    // and also allows Webpack to pick up changes.
    constructor(template?: T) {} 

    // ...some fields and methods

    get typedField(): T {
        return /* something slightly calculated */
    }
}
```

I'm using it like a type in my Typescript project:

```js
import GenericClass from "path/to/GenericClass"
import template from "template.json"

export type TemplateType = typeof template
export default new GenericClass(template)

// we can also write
//     export default new GenericClass<TemplateType>()
// but in this case the changes in template.json
// won't be picked up by Webpack.
// However, this does not affects the problem,
// it occurs in both cases.
```

I'm running the `webpack` dev-server, and use it somewhere:

```js
import * as React from "react"
import GenericInstance from "path/to/GenericInstance"

export default MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var { typedField } = GenericInstance
        return (
            <main>
                <p>{typedField.myField1} {/* ok */}</p>
                <p>{typedField.myField2} {/* ok */}</p>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

After that I'm adding a new field into my `template.json`:

```
{
    "myField1": "",
    "myField2": "",
    "myField3": ""   
}
```

Saving it. `webpack` dev-server picks up this change in `template.json`. Allright. **One important thing** is that autocomplete of VSCode works (it shows this `myField3` in list of available fields). Fine.

At this moment, when I'm trying to use `myField3` in `MyComponent` (like `<p>{typedField.myField3}</p>`), `awesome-typescript-loader` sends an error during compilation:

> Property 'myField3' does not exist on type '{ "myField1": string; "myField2": string; }'

Obviously, `awesome-typescript-loader` did not pick up changes in `template.json` which is used as type in my `GenericClass`.

How can I beat it? After restart of the dev-server it works fine until I make changes in `template.json`.

Partial `webpack.config.js`, `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`

```
config = {
    rules: {
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        },
    }
}
```

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3",
        "webpack": "^4.29.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strict": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "jsx": "react",
        "traceResolution": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

---

## Update

I can confirm that this occurs only with imported *.json. Probably, the problem can be in touch with `resolveJsonModule` setting for TypeScript, but not sure. Setting `useCache` and `usePrecompiledFiles` to `false` explicitly for `awesome-typescript-loader` in `webpack.config.js` does not help. I mean, changed `webpack.config.js` now looks like:

```
{
    test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
    options: {
        useCache: false,
        usePrecompiledFiles: false
    },
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!superagent)/,
},
```

Comment: Maybe the caching behaviour of modules is different when using json files as modules in typescript. Could you change that json file to a typescript module / object literal and export that?

Comment: @DerAlex Thank you for your comment. AFAIK, caching of files in `atl` is disabled by default. I understand what are you saying about, and, possibly, this is true, but if it is true, then, seems like, there is no way to fix it (according to `atl` docs). It will be hard for me to swap `json` with module or object literal, because a lot of things is dependent on it, but I will try :)

Comment: @DerAlex but I suppose it is not necessary to check it, because `atl` works clearly fine on changing of 
`.(j|t)sx?$` files

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Did you try this configure?: At `webpack.config.js` `loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
  options:
    useCache: false, usePrecompiledFiles: false`. Please double check because default is `false`.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn `useCache` and `usePrecompiledFiles` are `false` by default (according to [official docs](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#usecache-boolean-defaultfalse)), but I just forced this config and... nothing changed.

Comment: "After that I'm adding a new field into my template.json:" You missed a comma in the JSON bellow this sentence

Comment: @Seblor suggest an edit, I'll accept it :)

Comment: So it was just a typo in your question, then ?

Comment: @Seblor yes, definetly, just a typo. I created code in this question from the scratch)

Comment: @Seblor oh, you have a privilege to edit questions without confirmation!

Comment: Yes, you can edit questions and answers without waiting for approval after you reach 2000 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `awesome-typescript-loader`. As of v5.2.1, here's a quick fix:

```
// node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/instance.js

// ln: 214:
- var EXTENSIONS = /\.tsx?$|\.jsx?$/;
+ var EXTENSIONS = /\.tsx?$|\.jsx?|\.json$/;
```

Apparently the author forget to include `.json` extension as a valid target.

Comment: PR fired: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/pull/629

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm modified the file you have referred, but it did not solve the problem :(

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance That's weird. I was able to reproduce the error as per your description, and I solved mine by modified that line. Must be some other difference in our setup?

Comment: You might want to put a `console.log` in that `instance.js` file to check if it's the actual source file used by the `at-loader` instance.

Comment: Well, checked all, extensions are modified. Changed `import * as template from "template.json"` to `import template from "template.json"` and the issue disappeared. But your solution and pull request are totally right. Thank you!

Comment: However, I found something weird. It works only after triggering the OP error at once. I mean: Start server -> Manage `template.json` -> Save (*changed ARE NOT being picked up*) -> Use new field (*error triggered*) -> Manage `template.json` -> Save (*changes ARE being picked*) -> Use both new fields -> Everything is ok.

Comment: at-loader use a "checker" in other process to ts-check your code. Unlike tsc, it doesn't use native fs. Instead it uses webpack's internal virtual fs. This explain the diff in behavior.

Comment: Basically at-loader listen to changes in webpack's fs, filter to keep only ts related changes, then call `checker.updateFile()` for each changed file. In that `instance.js` you can log to see what "changes" are feed to checker to further pin point the problem.

Comment: Well, what I can see and confirm, that `watchRun` hook does not reacting on first save at all. I `console.log`ged the `fileName` inside `changedFiles.map`, and it does not being triggered during first save-update. It DOES emit changes for `ts` files, but does not for `json` on first load. After further updates everything is ok. Pretty strange thing. Well, thank you once more time, you solved a big problem)